# SD card trouble

Tags: samsung, sd-card, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-5, media-files

I have a 16GB Samsung Galaxy S5. I filled the memory so I bought a 32GB SD card to move my media onto. I copied the Media onto the SD card,  made sure everything transferred properly, and then deleted the media on the device memory. A few hours later,  I turned the phone off, switched batteries, and when I booted back up, a message popped up saying that the SD card was damaged. The phone will not recognize anything except that its installed. Please tell me there is a way to fix the SD card and recover my media with minimal loss! How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can download AParted from Google play store and from there go to tools and choose your sdcard  (mine is Part1 FS:fat32 Size:7888mb because my sdcard is 8GB I checked the first one) and then check your sdcard which you will know because of the size and choose repair and click apply, wait, you can apply it several times then reboot your phone and check if it is fix.

Hope it helps!